# How to use ngFor index variable in HTML element attribute value calculation?

Tags: angular, ngfor

I'm new to Angular and I searched around but can't find the answer to my question.

I have defined a variable in my class and plan to use it in the template.

```
public colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow'];
```

In the template, I have below code:

```
<div *ngFor="let c of colors; index as i">
    <div [style.width]="'100px'" [style.height]="{{(i+1)*10}}px" [style.backgroundColor]="c">{{c}}</div>
</div>
```

My intention is to calculate the CSS height by the formula `(i+1)*10`px. The syntax in the upper snippet is not correct. What's the correct way to implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove square brackets `[]`. Here is updated one below

```
<div *ngFor="let c of colors; let i  =  index">
    <div  style.height="{{(i+1)*10}}px" [style.backgroundColor]="c">{{c}}</div>
</div>
```

Have a look [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f83fyd)

Comment: I know this. My question is how to do the calculation using i for [style.height].

Answer (score 3):

You need something like this,

```
<div *ngFor="let c of colors; index as i">
    <div [style.width]="'100px'" [style.height]="(i+1)*10+'px'" [style.backgroundColor]="c">{{c}}</div>
</div>
```

[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pwlmy9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[style.height.px]` an attribute which explicitly tells unit, So in your case its `px` and then use your formula to calculate number:

```
<div *ngFor="let c of colors; index as i">
    <div [style.width]="'100px'" [style.backgroundColor]="c" [style.height.px]="((i+1)*10)">
      {{c}} {{i*10}}
    </div>
</div>
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-941n9c)